# Auth call errors signUpAppId is undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, okta

When I do a auth call using email, the function returns successful including the data expected, however leaves this console.error from `shared.js` (I assuming this is a Firebase file).

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.currentSelfServiceAppID.signUpAppId')`

I am using version `"firebase": "^6.6.1"`, and added the email I am using to auth my app via the Firebase console. The email has not been verified.

Is this error expected when the email has not been verified? Or is there another set up error I have missed?

Comment: Firebase does not have an API member `signUpAppId`. This error is likely not related to Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where this error is coming from. I have an Okta extension installed on my browser, and this is causing the error. It has nothing to do with Firebase, it's a bug with the extension.